# Search for coverings in hyperbolic tessellations

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, tessellations

Given a regular or uniform tessellation of hyperbolic plane, is there a way to find a group of cells that will tile the whole plane?

For example: in the $(6,6,7)$ tessellation (truncated $\{3,7\}$), the "ratio" of hexagons to heptagons is $7:3$ (as each vertex can be understood as $2\cdot 1/6$ of hexagon + $1/7$ of heptagon). A group of $7$ hexagons and $3$ heptagons could be theoretically a reptile (and any reptile must have a multiple of these numbers).

I know of one shape in this tessellation that will tile the whole hyperbolic plane -- it has 40 tiles (28 hexagons and 12 heptagons) and it's used in several ingenious ways in the game HyperRogue (http://zenorogue.blogspot.cz/2015/02/hyperrogue-60-five-new-lands.html has an explanation).

I'd like to find some alternate shapes to suggest for this game, but I'm not sure whether there has been any research done in this area.

Comment: The meaning of your question is not clear. There is a lot of undefined jargon and notation: What is a "reptile"? What is the "$(6,6,7)$ tesselation"? What does does "truncated $\{3,7\}$" mean? And so on...

Comment: (6,6,7) means a tessellation with configuration of hexagon, hexagon and heptagon around a vertex. This is a truncated form of {3,7}, a tessellation with seven triangles around each vertex. {3,7} is Schläfli symbol and "truncated" is a term defined for uniform tilings (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_order-7_triangular_tiling).

Comment: "Reptile" (I eventually realized this term is wrong here and tried to purge it from the question) is a shape whose copies can be used to assemble a larger version of itself; but that's actually impossible in hyperbolic plane -- what I mean is a shape that would tile the whole hyperbolic plane while simultaneously being composed of cells of the underlying tessellation.

Comment: Just an update, playing around in the game's sandbox mode I managed to find some new plane-tiling configurations with 10 and 50 cells, respectively.

Comment: no amount of tiles can ever tile the whole hyperbolic plane, (the hyperbolic plane is just to big for that)

Comment: @Willemien: Not sure what you mean. In a trivial case, a single tile of regular tessellation self-evidently DOES tile the whole hyperbolic plane.

Comment: In my problem it's about finding larger groupings of tiles in uniform (not regular) tessellation that can tile the plane.

Comment: you always  need an infinite number of tiles (it is  worse than the "normal" Euclidean plane) The hyperbolic plane has an infinite area, and every n-polygon has a fixed (limited) area, so you will always need an infinite number of them to tile the entire hyperbolic plane. You could make an exception for an one infinite size regular apeirogon ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apeirogon#Apeirogons_in_hyperbolic_plane ) but you cannot even cut that polygon in half, if you try you again get an infinite number of them. (each of the tilings has an infinite number of apeirogons)

Comment: @Willemien: I just don't understand what you're getting at. Of course I need infinite amount of individual polygons, just like when tiling a plane -- that's trivial. But I'm trying to find shapes based on a tessellation that will (in infinite quantity, of course), tile the hyperbolic plane with just their own copies.

Comment: but there are also finite amount of regulars uniform tilings  for the hyperbolic plane (so based around the same polygon) see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_tilings_in_hyperbolic_plane every n sided polygon  can tile the hyperbolic plane (see the examples in under regular uniform tilings all on a blue background are hyperbolic)

Comment: @Willemien; Yes, I'm aware of that. Once again, that's not what I'm looking for. What I'm looking for is an analogy to tiling the plane with identical copies of polyominoes (connected shapes made from squares). In the hyperbolic plane, such shapes, made from cells of an underlying tessellation, might ultimately lead to something topologically equivalent to a regular or uniform tessellations, but not actually made of regular shapes.

Comment: I thnk we can agree that we don't uderstand eachother :) can you add one of your new finds to the question? was wondering why are you limiting yourself to polygons where the sides are lines /geodesics, you could just also use one of the other special curves in the hyperbolicgeometry (will add a section about this later to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model )

Comment: Well, here's an [example](http://www.imagebam.com/image/034415424587445). This is a tiling pattern in underlying (6,6,7) tessellation. The four colors of shapes are just to distinguish them easily; they are all congruent.

Comment: my internet does not allow access to imagebarn :( could you just add thepicture to the question?)

Comment: Not sure how, it seems I can just add a link to the picture, not a picture from my disk, and so you're back where you were.